How to use Quarto- ojs and r code chunk integration
I am using a quarto document in Rstudio.
I can use ojs code chunk for interactive selection:
# ojs code chunk:
viewof range = Inputs.range([0, 100], {label: "Amount", step: 1})
viewof select = Inputs.select(["A", "B"], {label: "Select one"})


How can I use ojs variable (user inputs: 'range' value or 'select' in this case) to the next R chunk?
Is there any function/workaround to convert the inputs in ojs chunk into R object?

Looks like this is not possible except via Shiny. See https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/612
